# Ensuring that a maven build is self-contained

Tags: maven

In a medium-sized maven project (>40 modules), refactoring the module structure can easily make the build refer to modules that no longer exist (e.g., because they were renamed). Unfortunately, the project will still build, because it will automatically fetch the (outdated) versions of the old modules from the repository. However, I'd want the build to fail immediately instead.

Is it possible to tell maven that artefacts with a certain groupId should not always be built locally?

Comment: Interesting question. I don't think it's possible to do exactly what you ask. I'd do the following way: 1) use `versions` plugin to update all of the modules and module inter-dependencies to some non-existing version (f.e., 123-321-SNAPSHOT) 2) build the project. In this case build will fail when maven won't be able to find dependency on non-existing module of the version above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking a bit more, it seems that one rather straightforward way of ensuring integrity is

1. Run a full build

   `mvn clean install`
2. Remove the relevant portions in the local repository

   `rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/DIR_FOR_MY_GROUPID`
3. Run an offline build

   `mvn -o clean install`

The last step will fail if we depend on anything in the given groupId that is not a product of the same build.

Answer (score 2):

For this very same problem I have a cron job (or jenkins job) to clear my local repo once a week. It is not a perfect solution since the build will continue to build incorrectly for (worst case) 1 week until it will fail.

If you want something more controlled, you can add `dependency:purge-local-repository` as a previous goal, something like `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository deploy` . More info [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/purging-local-repository.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, the obsolete dependency will then be drawn from our local Nexus repository, so I'd have to clear that one as well...

Answer (score 0):

My prefered way to solve this is command `rm -Rf ~/.m2/repository`.

For doing this internal repository manager like Nexus or Artifactory is recommended.

Comment: Doesn't help if the obsolete artifacts are available from the internal Nexus/Artifactory.